# Sorted search in two different collections in Apache Solar

Tags: solr

I have two Apache Solar collections, the first collection containing information for the past year and the second collection containing information up to one year old (as shown below)
My problem is doing sorted search between two collections.
For example, I want to search data between 300-400 days ago in a sort order, the problem is that I do not know how to do it by most accurate and fastest way.

[image: collections]

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Collection alias that spans both collections](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-createalias) - i.e. give both collection names in the `collections` list when creating the alias:

```
/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=name&collections=uptopastyear,pastyeartonow
```

You can then query this collection with a regular range filter:

```
&fq=datetime:[<timestamp 400 days ago> TO <timestamp 300 years ago>]
```

Comment: I want to use the first collection if the time range was in now to one year ago, but Alice is not do it.

Comment: That'll have to be logic in your controller / client; there is no way to do route requests like that on the Solr side.